# values in queue Java

Tags: java

If I have a queue with strings as values How would I print all the values I was using:

```
System.out.println(queue.elements().toString().);
```

But it prints java objects...?

Do I have to use a loop to print values of queue?

Comment: does java have somethjing like `reduce` or `fold`?  otherwise i dont see any way around a loop

Comment: actually scratch that, i think there are some `toString` that operate on a whole array or list.  what type is queue?  if it is a `Queue` then there is no such method as `elements()` just `element()` which returns the queue's head

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use a loop however the loop can be simple like.

```
for(String s : queue) { 
  System.out.println(s.toString()); 
}
```

Actually, as long as it implements Iterable you should be able to do this type of foreach loop.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html This has more information about the Java foreach, but the for(<type> var : <iterable of type>) {} makes it so that you don't have to keep track of list iterators and there is no "off by one" issues.

Comment: You can actually just write `System.out.println(queue);`, unless you want more control over the output format.

Comment: @David Conrad: It would depend on if the queue variable type actually implements a toString() function that automatically prints out all of the elements.

Comment: I assumed we were talking about `java.util.Queue`. All the implementations of it in the standard `java.util` package (indeed, all the implementations of all the standard Java collections API) have nice `toString()` methods. I suppose if you rolled your own you could forget to provide `toString()`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand your question. You say you want to print strings, and then after some code that doesn't compile, you say, "But it prints java objects...?" Strings **are** Java objects.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>(); // create queue

        for (String name : args) queue.add(name); // add strings to queue

        System.out.println(queue); // print entire queue at once

        for (String s : queue) System.out.println(s); // print each separately
    }
}
```

Run with e.g., `java Foo apple banana pear`. The output is:

```
[apple, banana, pear]
apple
banana
pear
```

If the problem is that you are getting output like this:

```
[MyObject@498b5a73, MyObject@5bdf59bd, MyObject@247cb66a]
MyObject@498b5a73
MyObject@5bdf59bd
MyObject@247cb66a
```

Then your Queue does not actually hold Strings, and you have forgotten to override the `toString()` method in your class:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + quest + ", " + favoriteColor;
}
```

There is no need to use a loop, unless you don't `[like, this, output, format]`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of `queue`.

- If it is a `Queue` or `Deque`, then your code won't compile, because these interfaces don't define an `elements()` method.  This applies to most of the classes that implement `Collection`.
- If it is a `Vector`, then the `elements()` returns an `Enumeration`, and you have to use a loop to pull the values from it.

My advice would be:

- Stop using `Vector` ... unless you have no choice.  Vector is a legacy class.  Use one of the implementations of `Queue` or `Deque` instead.
- Whether or not you use `Vector`, use `queue.toString()` rather than `queue.elements().toString()` to render the queue contents as a String.  The `toString()` method is defined as rendering the elements of the collection for all of the standard collection classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Enumeration e = queue.elements();
 while ( e.hasMoreElements() )
    System.out.println( e.nextElement() );
```

Comment: `Enumeration` is dead. Let it rest in peace. Use `Iterable` and `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) in guava.

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on("\n").join(queue.elememts()));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import java.util.LinkedList;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
> import java.util.Queue;
>
> public class Main {
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
> Queue myQueue = new LinkedList();
>
> ```
> myQueue.add("A");
> myQueue.add("B");
> myQueue.add("C");
> myQueue.add("D");
>
> List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(myQueue);
>
> for (Object theFruit : myList)
>   System.out.println(theFruit);
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: Why create a copy of the Queue as an ArrayList and loop over that, instead of just looping over the Queue? Also, why declare the loop variable to be Object instead of String?

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.8+ solution:

```
queue.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You can also use the lambda way  queue.forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));