# How can i print all the values of a queue without changing the queue?(JAVA)

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I am trying to print my values from queue without modifying the queue basically ı want my queue to be same before and after the print. I thought to copy the elements to a temporary queue and print the values from it but it is space inefficient i guess, do you guys have any better approach or solution ?

Comment: What?  Surely, printing is a read-only operation?  Please explain your problem.

Comment: I didn't fully explain my situation i guess. I need to print my queue without changing it queue is my own implementation btw not regular java queue and i can only use queue operations for example printing the queue with using the feature of array inside of the queue is forbiden because of that i was looking for a better way than what i explained in the question

Comment: Well then, with no code, we cannot help.

Comment: giving a idea is forbiden  ? i don't want a code from anyone i just want a better aproach idea if you guys have any i am already doing it with using temporary queue just want to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Two users,have resorted to answers by guessing.  They guessed wrong.  If you have a queue class of your own, please give details!

Answer (score -1):

Shortest is to do a lambda on queue's forEach, something like the following:

```
queue.forEach(s -> System.out.println("Do your thing."));
```

Doing this you won't change the queue.

Other ideas:
[values in queue Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413934/values-in-queue-java)

Answer (score -1):

java.util.Queue have a `peek()` method.

Documentation said:

> E peek()
>   Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.
>   Returns:
>   the head of this queue, or null if this queue is empty.

Hope this help you!

Comment: i created my queue using a array :/

Comment: @Teurin And your queue need to a method like `peek()` ??